# Get all directories and catch permissions exception and continue

Tags: c#

```
public void newestFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in dir.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var file = item.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }                     
}
```

I want to get the newest file from each directory from specific path and continue after catch the permission exception, currently my code stuck in catch and not continue.

Comment: Nitpick: You should only catch-ignore the *specific* exception you want to ignore, e.g., an `UnauthorizedAccessException` in your case. Otherwise, you might accidentally swallow other exceptions as well, creating hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: search top directory only and do your own recursive loop

Comment: Not sure why your searching for directories with a `.` in them either but thats just more nitpicking (I presume you have a reason)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Microsoft's implementation of `GetDirectories()` is extremely poor, and doesn't handle IO exceptions relating to access rights.

If you want to just skip over directories that you don't have access to (such as the special `Recycle Bin` folder, for example), then you have to write your own wrapper for the Windows API functions `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()`.

Here's a complete example. If you run it, you'll see that it lists *all* the accessible directories on your C: drive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            string root = "C:\\";

            foreach (var folder in FolderEnumerator.EnumerateFoldersRecursively(root))
                Console.WriteLine(folder);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }

    public static class FolderEnumerator
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFoldersRecursively(string root)
        {
            foreach (var folder in EnumerateFolders(root))
            {
                yield return folder;

                foreach (var subfolder in EnumerateFoldersRecursively(folder))
                    yield return subfolder;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFolders(string root)
        {
            WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
            string spec = Path.Combine(root, "*");

            using (SafeFindHandle findHandle = FindFirstFile(spec, out findData))
            {
                if (!findHandle.IsInvalid)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if ((findData.cFileName != ".") && (findData.cFileName != ".."))  // Ignore special "." and ".." folders.
                        {
                            if ((findData.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) != 0)
                            {
                                yield return Path.Combine(root, findData.cFileName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    while (FindNextFile(findHandle, out findData));
                }
            }
        }

        internal sealed class SafeFindHandle: SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
        {
            [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]

            public SafeFindHandle(): base(true)
            {
            }

            protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
            {
                if (!IsInvalid && !IsClosed)
                {
                    return FindClose(this);
                }

                return (IsInvalid || IsClosed);
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!IsInvalid && !IsClosed)
                {
                    FindClose(this);
                }

                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct FILETIME
        {
            public uint dwLowDateTime;
            public uint dwHighDateTime;

            public long ToLong()
            {
                return dwLowDateTime + ((long)dwHighDateTime) << 32;
            }
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]

        internal struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
        {
            public FileAttributes dwFileAttributes;
            public FILETIME       ftCreationTime;
            public FILETIME       ftLastAccessTime;
            public FILETIME       ftLastWriteTime;
            public int            nFileSizeHigh;
            public int            nFileSizeLow;
            public int            dwReserved0;
            public int            dwReserved1;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=MAX_PATH)]
            public string cFileName;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=MAX_ALTERNATE)]
            public string cAlternate;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern SafeFindHandle FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool FindNextFile(SafeHandle hFindFile, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool FindClose(SafeHandle hFindFile);

        private const int MAX_PATH = 260;
        private const int MAX_ALTERNATE = 14;
    }
}
```

Note: This code uses `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` which iterate through all folders AND files. The code above is just ignoring the files and only returning the folders.

It would be more efficient to use [`FindFirstFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specify a flag to return only directories. I leave that change as the proverbial exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: What i need to change in this class in order to received only directories with permission ?

Comment: @user2214609 It already does give you only the directories you have permission to read from. The line `if (!findHandle.IsInvalid)` is protecting against the invalid ones.

Comment: So why it returning all th directories from C include the Recycle Bin ?

Comment: I opened this post because my function crash due to access denied

Comment: Would you mind explaining the line "[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]" and how one should replace "LinkDemand" with "SecurityCriticalAttribute"?

Answer (score 0):

```
public string[] newestFile(string path){    
    IEnumerable<string> files = new string[]{};
    foreach (var item in dir.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(path,"*.*"), SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
       try {
        files = files.Concat(item.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First());
       }
       catch {}
    }   
    return files.ToArray();  
}
```